# Complete separation in logistic regression with only one direction

Tags: r, logistic, separation

In this paper [Dealing with Separation in Logistic Regression Models](http://www.carlislerainey.com/papers/separation.pdf) some various types of complete separation are discussed:

direction of the separation is positive if and only if $s_i = 1 \Rightarrow y_i = 1$ or $s_i = 0 \Rightarrow y_i = 0$

direction of the separation is negative if and only if $s_i = 0 \Rightarrow y_i = 1$ or $s_i = 1 \Rightarrow y_i = 0$

I'm wondering if this can be also called complete separation:

$s_i = 0 \Rightarrow y_i = 1$ AND $s_i = 1 \Rightarrow y_i = 1$

I call this *one direction* to distinct it from the other two.

Here I have the corresponding showcases to make it clear:

posivite direction:

```
          out
group    0  1
  ctrl  20  0
  treat  0 20
```

negative direction:

```
          out
group    0  1
  ctrl   0 20
  treat  20 0
```

one direction

```
          out
group    0  1
  ctrl   0 20
  treat  0 20
```

My questions are:

- Can this be also called complete separation?
- May I use the same tools (for example bayesglm from R) to analyze this kind of complete separation?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your question is that you treat logistic regression as a classifier, that is for you it outputs *clases*.  But that is not logistic regression (LR), LR estimates ("outputs") *probabilities*, see for example [Why isn't Logistic Regression called Logistic Classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification/127044#127044)  or  [Logistic regression - how good is my model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130420/logistic-regression-how-good-is-my-model/130446#130446) .

The paper you linked do not have a correct definition of complete separation, it says that only occurs *if it is caused by one variable $s_i$*. That is not correct, complete separation can well occur without any single variable causing it.  So maybe you should find some better source of basic information on LR, maybe [https://www.amazon.com/Regression-Modeling-Strategies-Applications-Statistics/dp/0387952322](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952322)  (there are also many good posts on this site).

Comment: Thanks for reply and the very interesting links. I don't use logistic regression as classifier but as modelling tool to estimates odds ratio. I just wondered if it is correct to call separation if all outcomes of one predictor is 1. Thinking again about this _special_ case I would just omit this predictor.

Comment: Why would you *omit* it? Does not make sense, that it separates shows that it is a very good predictor!